# Kivy, any chegar sweet or reference Guide?

Tags: kivy

Im not a complete noob but I'm relearning to code,  I know the basic python and I whant to Learn kivy.  But im finding the few docs avaliable a little confusing...  Since my best bet  is to Learn by try and error Im looking for a cheat sweet or similar,  with the basic sintax... Is there any online?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I will provide you basic links that will help you get started.
You can view [Kivy examples](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/tree/master/examples) or you can view [snippet wiki](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki) for more clarity.
[Programming guide](https://kivy.org/docs/guide-index.html) and [getting started](https://kivy.org/docs/gettingstarted/index.html#doc-introduction) will help you get started.
You can solve or open [issues](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues) for more understanding of code base.

If you like videos then these youtube videos will help you.

[Kivy tut by sentdex](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CYNWK2GpwgA&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDe_l6XiJ40yGTEqIKugAdTy)

[Kivy tut by Alexander Taylor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7UKmK9eQLY&list=PLdNh1e1kmiPP4YApJm8ENK2yMlwF1_edq)